Имеется ли в предложении присоединительная конструкция? Нужна ли запятая?
Верна ли пунктуация в следующем предложении?
Мы идём по главному коридору тюрьмы, и на этот раз совсем недолго - через десятка два шагов мой провожатый останавливается напротив одной из дверей
Запятая нужна, потому что "и на этот раз совсем недолго" - это присоединительная конструкция? А тире поставлено перед пояснением?

Правильно:
Мы идём по главному коридору тюрьмы, и на этот раз (идем) совсем недолго — через десятка два шагов мой провожатый останавливается напротив одной из дверей.
Пояснение
В предложении нет добавочных сообщений — все они являются равноправными. Поэтому лучше объяснить постановку знаков следующим образом.
Это сложное предложение с тремя предикативными основами, поэтому можно для анализа использовать метод блоков  ПАС под ред. Лопатина.
  § 132. В сложных синтаксических конструкциях, 
  распадающихся на крупные логико-синтаксические блоки, 
  которые сами по себе являются сложными предложениями или в 
  которых один из блоков оказывается сложным предложением, 
  на стыке блоков ставятся знаки препинания, указывающие на 
  взаимоотношения блоков, при сохранении внутренних знаков, 
  поставленных на своем собственном синтаксическом 
  основании.

Два блока, граница между блоками на месте постановки тире.
В первой части сочинительная связь, обозначенная запятой, союз И. Второе предложение продолжает тему первого (на этот раз, отношения соединительно-распространительные).
Между блоками бессоюзная связь, отношения пояснительные (как недолго), используется тире.

Большое спасибо!
